# `io.netty` exception when implementing Spring Session with Redis

Tags: redis, netty, spring-session

I am implementing Spring Session with Redis.

I am getting the following exception:

```
SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks 
The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] 
(value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@e9d8bb]) and a value of type [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap] 
(value [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@1559b23]) 
but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be 
renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

I have the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
        <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I can see that `lettuce-core` is dragging in the `io.netty` classes:

```
[INFO] +- io.lettuce:lettuce-core:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.43.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.43.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.43.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.43.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.43.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.43.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
```

The `io.netty` exception is a [known, unfixed defect](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/6891).

Is there a way to work around this?  I've already tried the following:

- Used version 5.1.8.RELEASE of `lettuce-core`: Same exception
- Used version 5.0.5.RELEASE of `lettuce-core`: Get NoSuchMethodError: io.lettuce.core.api.StatefulConnection.closeAsync()

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The bug report comments indicate this will mitigate the problem, but will not fully solve it.  Perhaps an approach like the following will be good enough for your use case?

```
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap.destroy();
    }

}
```